# Counting AND printing values in Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am writing a code, that runs a collection through a stream, and in the stream it filters the data with several filter functions, and then prints the result of filtering:

```
List<String> someList = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", etc.);

someList.stream().filter(s -> predicate1()).filter(s -> predicate2()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and what would greatly help me, would be the ability to **print and count** filtered elements. Since `forEach()` uses consumer function, and returns `Void` type, I cannot do anything further to the data. But if I change `forEach()` with `count()`, I receive a `long` value, and stream is ended this way or another.
Is there any elegant way to have something like:

```
long counted = someList.stream().filter(s -> predicate1()).filter(s -> predicate2()).map??reduce??(printAndAlsoCountPrintedAndReturnFinalCountValue())
```

in one stream without having to run it 2 times, first with `count()`, and the second with `forEach(System.out::println)`? I was thinking about some mapper function, but `map()` also returns `Stream<R>` data, so even if I did some mapping printing-counting function, I don't see how I'd have to return counted value into a parameter.

Generally it's not a problem to run the collection through 2 streams, but I believe it's not very resource-wise, depending on how heavy the filtering functions would be, that's why I am looking for more "clever" solution, if it exists.

Comment: Can’t you count in the forEach incrementing a counter and also print the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really intended to be used for that, but you could use an `AtomicLong`.

```
    List<String> someList  = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "s1", "s2");
    AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong();
    someList .stream()
            .filter(s -> s.contains("string"))
            .forEach(s -> {
                System.out.println(s);
                count.incrementAndGet();
            });
    System.out.println(count.get());
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally used '''AtomicLong''' for counter. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` function:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var l = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
        var count= l.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x%2 == 0)
                    .reduce(0, (acc, elem) -> {
                        System.out.println(elem);
                        return acc + 1; 
                    });
        System.out.println("Total Count: " + count);
    }
}
```

This will print “Total Count: 4” as well as the elements themselves (2,4,6,8)

Note that this printing is a side effect so personally I would also consider writing this “as usual” with for-loops (in an imperative style) without streams at all.

Comment: That's OK, but works only for Streams of numerical values, and since someList consists of Strings, the ```acc``` parameter is expected to be string in provided reduce function.

Comment: Nope, acc is still the same, initialized with 0 it gets increased and contains an actual count of the elements that were processed so far. At the end it will contain an actual count of what you need. Change the stream to "a" "b" "c" and see....

Answer (score 2):

If you need to see all the elements that passed all the filters in the pipeline on the console, you can use `peek()`. This method was introduces in the Stream API for debugging.

```
long counted = someList.stream()
    .filter(s -> predicate1())
    .filter(s -> predicate2())
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .count();
```

***Note:*** that this method should be used **only** for debugging purposes. If let's say instead of printing you would decide to store these elements into a collection, then you need to be aware that it's **discouraged** by [*API the documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

And, also, pay attention to the documentation of [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer))

> This method **exists mainly** to **support debugging**, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline
>
> In cases where the stream implementation is able to **optimize away** the
> production of some or all the elements (such as with *short-circuiting
> operations* like `findFirst`, or in the example described in `count()`),
> the action **will not be invoked for those elements**.

That means when have in mind something more important than printing elements on the console (and you don't want this action to be optimized away), then you can generate a collection as a result. And then you can do whatever you need with its contents and find out its size as well.

```
public List<String> foo(List<String> source) {
    
    return source.stream()
        .filter(s -> predicate1())
        .filter(s -> predicate2())
        .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```